# Proving $\frac{\sin^2(x+y)+\sin^2(x-y)}{2 \cos^2(x)\cos^2(y)}=\tan^2(x)+\tan^2(y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I tried to prove that
$$\frac{\sin^2(x+y)+\sin^2(x-y)}{2 \cos^2(x)\cos^2(y)}=\tan^2(x)+\tan^2(y)$$

Got it to
$$\frac {2 \sin(x) \sin(y)}{\cos(x)\cos(y)}=\tan^2(x)+\tan^2(y)$$ but got stuck here.

Comment: Could you show how you simplified the denominator to $2\sin x\sin y$? That's not correct.

Comment: In your work, did you mistake a "$+$" for a "$-$" on the left-hand side?

Comment: @Blue Yeah, I did .Thanks

Comment: @J.G. Mistook a "+" for a "-" , that's why I got to that result.

Comment: @qqqq: If you had continued, you could've written $$2\tan x\tan y = \tan^2x+\tan^2y \quad\to\quad 0 = (\tan x-\tan y)^2$$ That might've told you there was something amiss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\sin^2(x+y)+\sin^2(x-y)}{2 \cos^2(x)\cos^2(y)}= \frac{(\sin(x) \cos(y) + \cos(x)\sin(y))^2 + (\sin(x) \cos(y) - \cos(x)\sin(y))^2}{ 2 \cos^2(x)\cos^2(y)} = \frac{2(\sin(x) \cos(y))^2 + 2(\cos(x)\sin(y))^2 }{2 \cos^2(x)\cos^2(y)}.$$ Now split the bottom, and you're done. Note that in the third line, I used the following identity:

$(a+b)^2 +(a-b)^2 = 2(a^2 +b^2).$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Cross multiply denominator and break the sine multiple angles.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the issue at its beginning: do you know twin trigonometric formulas:

$$\begin{cases}\tan(a)+\tan(b)&=&\dfrac{\sin(a+b)}{\cos(a)\cos(b)}\\
\tan(a)-\tan(b)&=&\dfrac{\sin(a-b)}{\cos(a)\cos(b)}
\end{cases} \ ?$$

Just square them and add them...

**Remark:** the second formula is obtained by changing $b$ into $-b$ into the first one.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin(x + y) = \sin x \cos y + \cos x \sin y$ and $\sin(x - y) = \sin x \cos y - \cos x \sin y$, therefore $$\sin^2(x + y) - \sin^2(x - y) = 4\sin x \cos y \cos x \sin y$$